# How to setup my Feature.xml for a SharePoint timer job?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-timer-job

I have a class like this:

```
namespace SharePointSocialNetworking
{   
    public class FeatureToEnableJob : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
      public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
      {

        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

        // Make sure the job isn't already registered.
        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
        {
            if (job.Name == "SPFacebookJob")
                job.Delete();
        }

        // Install the job.
        Facebook fbJob = new Facebook();

        SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
        schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
        schedule.EndSecond = 59;
        schedule.Interval = 2;
        fbJob.Schedule = schedule;

        fbJob.Update();
      }
      ...
    }

}
```

And this is my feature XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" 
 Id="b9e40341-32ab-410a-a20f-282cf13fb54b" 
 ReceiverAssembly="SharePointSocialNetworking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6264b0911592ad29" 
 ReceiverClass="SharePointSocialNetworking.FeatureToEnableJob" 
 Scope="Farm" 
 Title="SharePoint Social Networking Job">
</Feature>
```

My assembly is called SharePointSocialNetworking.  Am I doing anything wrong here?

I've done all the appropriate setup but when I run this command:

```
 stsadm -o installfeature -name SharePointSocialNetworking
```

I get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your feature parent is not a site but the farm, you should not cast it to SPSite